# How to enable pathautocompletion from windows commandline

Tags: php, command-line

I want to ask the user to locate a folder on the (windows) commandline. 
Usually you'll be able to use autocomplete with the [tab] key.
But not if I ask this from a phpscript.

I use this class:

```
<?php

class CLQuestion
{

    protected $_awnser;
    protected $_options;
    protected $_question;

    public function __construct($question, $options = array())
    {
        $this->_question = $question;
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->askQuestion();
        $this->waitForAwnser();
    }

    protected function askQuestion()
    {
        echo PHP_EOL . $this->_question . PHP_EOL;
    }

    protected function waitForAwnser()
    {
        while (true) {
            $response = strtolower(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
            // are options given?
            if (empty($this->_options)) {
                // no options given, so the response is our awnser
                $this->_awnser = $response;
                break;
            } else if (!empty($this->_options) && in_array($response, $this->_options)) {
                // options given and found in options
                $this->_awnser = $response;
                break;
            } else {
                // options given and not found.
                echo PHP_EOL . 'Please use one of these options: ';
                echo PHP_EOL . " " . implode(PHP_EOL . " ", $this->_options);
                echo PHP_EOL;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getAwnser()
    {
        return $this->_awnser;
    }

}
```

With this usage:

```
<?php 
$question = new CLQuestion('Where is you folder located?');
$question->getAwnser(); // path typed
```

Windows CMD will give me a way to interact, but when i use the [tab] key, it does not autocomplete but it show a tab. 
Am I able to activate path autocompletion in some way?

Comment: Minimal correction: `Answer =/= Awnser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autocompletion is a feature of a windows shell prompt.
When you run an application like:

```
 php script.php
```

this application gains control over STDIN and STDOUT and magic shell features like autocompletion will work no more until this app finishes.

This for example allows you to run one shell inside another.

If you need autocompletion in your script, you will need to implement it yourself. Instead of reading whole line with fgets(STDIN) you could read it char by char with fgetc(STDIN) and when the char will equal "\t" you would have to list files in current directory with php functions and check witch paths are matching to what user have written till now. So you will basically have to re-implement fgets adding magic autocompletion feature.

But instead of doing this and implementing your own shell I guess it would be far more better to make the folder location a script argument:

```
<?php

if(empty($argv[1])) die("usage: php script.php folderpath");
echo "your folder is located at:" . $argv[1];
```

So you could call it from windows shell like:

```
#php script.php
usage: php script.php folderpath
#php script.php foldername
your folder is located at: foldername
```

And then the autocompletion feature will work.

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation. I will take a look at fgetc()

Comment: How could i write to the STDIN, in this case? I cant get it to overwrite to text that is already typed.

Comment: you should write the rest of the path to STDOUT

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt update imidiatly, only after i press the enter key.

Comment: yes, the solution you picked is a lot harder than using command line argument so I think you should reconsider this. if you want out to update immediately please check manual for flush() function. also keep in mind that you are reimplementing fgets so you need also to support enter key, backspace etc.

Comment: You are generally trying to write your own shell witch might be good for educational purposes but not the best solution for doing things.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Ill use the argument as my first solution, but if I would need to enter multiple paths this might be the way on the usability. But in the end I'm stubborn and want to try out new stuff :)